# How to output in separate text files output of commands I type and the rest output of a program itself

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to automate process of input thousands or even millions of commands to a program and add conditions on each and every command output, so I could check errors, retry/skip.

```
@ECHO OFF
TYPE commands-list.txt | java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar application.jar > output.txt
FINDSTR /R /N "^.*" output.txt | FIND /C ":" > output-counter.txt
```

example of a commands-list.txt

```
list
stop
```

here I got complication because this program outputs not only output of commands I TYPE, but also some other output it makes while running process. So my question is how to output in separate text files output of commands I TYPE and the rest output of a program itself?

Comment: I don't think the question makes sense without an example of that `commands-list.txt`, output from the java app for one arbitrary command, possible condition(s), error handling you want to have, etc.

Comment: @wOxxOm, doesn't matter what commands you type, what conditions are possible. what errors it outputs. You can use any available application instead with any conditions you want and handle any sort of errors you can imagine. I'm just asking how to make output to separate file. My explanation not so good I guess, but I try realy hard. Sorry, if this doen't make sense to you.

Comment: **1.** If the output of commands you type are text strings and the other output it makes are also text strings, then it must be a difference between both texts that allows to differentiate them; otherwise, is not possible to achieve your request. **2.** To count the number of lines in a file, this method is simpler: `FIND /C /V "" < output.txt > output-counter.txt`

Comment: @qpaycm, `commands I TYPE into process` looks like a reference to `TYPE commands-list.txt` because of the irrelevant capitalization, that's why the question didn't make any sense, now thanks to Aacini, it does.

Comment: @Aacini, (1) obviously I hoped there is some way to push commands into running process and output strings into separate file somehow. That could make my life much easier. Thanks for breaking off my dreams :) (2) thanks alot! Best solution I found!

Comment: @wOxxOm, it is a reference. Truly sorry for what you have confused. Must be my english cause I really don't get where is the problem you talking about.

Comment: Are the output of "commands you type" comprised of certain command-names that does not appear in the "output it makes"? If so, then you could create a file with all command-names and then use `findstr` to separate output lines that have these command-names from those that have not.

Comment: It sounds like you will need to change the Java program to write another file with the commands it is processing from `commands-list.txt`.

Comment: @Aacini, yes, I know. The only issue to parse this strings is my knowledge of batch-scripting and this is fixable.

Comment: @Liturgist, unfortunately the official distribution is not open-source.

Comment: Just edit the question to change the topic title by something like "How to separate lines of a text file that have certain words", slightly change the description (I suggest you to remove any reference to "java") and include a (short) list of command-names as example (the solution to this question is a simple `findstr` command)!

Comment: is there a Java equivalent to the cmd `@`? Could be a fine filter criteria.